# is it best practice to consider the integer function result as a boolean

Tags: c

imagine we have a function:

```
static int do_job(int v)
{
    return (v > 10);
}
```

Then in other position of the code, we make that:

```
int job = /* some value */;

if (do_job(job)) {
   /* do something */
}
```

or

```
if (!do_job(job)) {
   /* do something */
}
```

i know we can do it, but is it a good practice to do that?

Comment: Why not `static bool do_job(int v)`?

Comment: People are commonly doing this. But if it is possible to use proper types - use them. Both for readability, self-documenting and possible error avoidance.

Comment: Personally I don't like this. It's more clear to use exactly what I intend. That is, `bool`s for true/false, `enum`s for distinct states, and `int`s for ints. Although, there was a time when `C` didn't have `bool` types, so it isn't all that uncommon to see `C` code like this. I don't know if `bool`s are supported in the standard or not, I'm sure someone here knows.

Comment: @yano It is there since C99.

Comment: The current C Standard (C11 draft 7.18) supports the intrinsic type `_Bool`, it also defines a macro `bool` expanding to `_Bool`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. good to know, thanks

Comment: The code in the question is perfectly reasonable for pre-1999 C.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but I'd be careful with using `int` returns as a true-false boolean equivalent. There's a lot of (older) functions that return the falsy `0` to indicate _"success"_, like `remove` -> returns 0 on success. This is especially true when you look at (string) comparison functions (`strcmp`, `memcmp`). I'd be tempted to use the `bool` type (`_Bool`), of only for clarity. If you're really looking for some semi-rational arguments, consider posting some code like this [on the codereview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem There is a good reason for `*cmp` functions to work like this. They are returning more then just two values.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know, that's why I mentioned `remove`, too (returns either 0 or -1). The point that I was trying to make is that, if I see a function returning  a `bool`, I _know_ what how to use the return value, and I know what it can tell me. An `int` could either be a function returning `0` on success, and any number of other values for various types of errors, _or_ it can be a function that returns an `int` to be used in some other way. If the OP is writing functions that check something that is either true or false, using the return type that best reflects this makes sense IMHO.

Comment: @alk: AFAIK, there aren't any. I believe the whole reason why C99 decided to introduce the type as `_Bool` and to define the macro's in a separate header was to not break existing code (there's probably hundreds of projects with some `typedef` or macro's that introduce `bool`). defining the macro's in existing header files might have pissed some people off :)

Comment: Sry, my initial comment @EliasVanOotegem comment above refers to was the question whether the C Standard (or even POSXI) defines any functions returning `_Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a good practice since

```
(v > 10)
```

can literally have only two values : `true` or `false`.

A type smaller than `int` may be used as the type of `do_job`, eg.

```
static bool do_job(int v)
```

the type bool is defined into stdbool.h

This yields a smaller function.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. Internally `bool` is often represented as the native integer type anyway.

Comment: `(v > 10)` evaluates to an `int`.

Comment: @alk I wonder if there is a good reason for that except the historical one...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, there's no reason other than the historical one. If C had had `bool` from the beginning, the equality and relational operators almost certainly would have been defined to yield a `bool` result. Since C didn't originally have `bool`, they were defined to yield an `int` value of `0` or `1` -- and when `_Bool` and `bool` were added in C99, the existing behavior of the equality and relational operators was not changed.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Perhaps to keep things simple? `char`, `int`, `float` along with `long` and you're done ... ;-)

Comment: @EugeneSh. : Agree to what you said in the beginning. But is not a shorter intergral type recommended if the case permits?